# How could I write an egrep command that will find all entries that have least 5 consecutive vowels (aeiou) in them upper or lower case?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I'm looking for an answer that doesnt include -i option to get both upper and lowercase. Specifically just how to make the regular expression itself output such a string.

I also do not want it to return any other strings outside of the consecutive "aeiou". For example I want to see:

aeiou
AEIOU
AeIou
daeiou
aeioud

etc.

I do not want to see:
AAAAA
aeiou
AEIOU
AeIou
daeiou
aeioud
AEODN
EEEEE
eaeee

when I do grep -E '[aeiou-AEIOU]{5,} it is still giving me additional strings like the ones above I do not want to see. Any ideas??

Comment: Try `grep -E '[aeiou-AEIOU]{5,}'`  add the `-o` option if needed?

Comment: No, this just outputs any string that contains at least 5 alphabetic values. I'm more so looking to output "aeiou" "AEIOU" "aEioU" "daeiou" "aeiouF" etc

Comment: I have tried it. `grep -E '[aeiou-AEIOU]{5,}' <<< '"AEIOU" "aEioU" "daeiou" "aeiouF"'`

Comment: just `[aeiouAEIOU]` should be sufficient. (no `-` char, that is). Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter, right why didn't I thought of that? :-), I was thinking range inside a character class...

Comment: The problem with that is will still output "AAAAA" or "AIEEE" for example. Whereas I want it to output ONLY if those vowels are consecutive

Comment: Well I guess your idea of "5 consecutive vowels" and that of the rest of the world differ.  You don't want 5 consecutive vowels, you want these 5 vowels in that order, independent of capitalisation? @shellter 's response does exactly what your question stipulates.

Comment: Please clarify the question, otherwise it will probably be downvoted or attract more “close” votes.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the misunderstanding. Let's say I have a dictionary of strings, and I only want to return the strings that have 'aeiou' consecutively and no other strings. When I use the commands on this thread, it's still returning additional strings. Not sure what I'm doing wrong that is getting a different output. But yes, the provided command will return "aeiou" AEIOU" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use `-i`, things like `[aA]` will serve instead to match an upper or lower case version of a particular letter:

```
grep '[aA][eE][iI][oO][uU]' <<< '"AEIOU" "aEioU" "daeiou" "aeiouF"'
```

Works fine with basic regular expressions, no need for extended (Which should be used via `grep -E`, not the obsolete `egrep`, by the way).

Comment: yes, agree, please specify why the downvote (this would have been my solution). Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with grep -E! This works with "{5,} at the end of the statement to get them consecutively.